# PHP GD extension works on the command line but Apache fails to load on Mac OS X Server

Tags: php, macos, gd, osx-server

When I start PHP from the command line, I get:

```
app1-test:wp-content wouser$ php -i | grep -i gd
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
```

But when I start Apache I get the following error (And the library doesn't show up in phpinfo):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/gd.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm trying to enable GD support without entirely recompiling PHP. But I'm about to give up. Its odd that it works fine on the command line but not during Apache load.

Any one have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When it's running from CLI, it's running under your user ID. When it's in Apache, it's running under Apache's user ID and/or "nobody". Could be a permissions issue. or you've got multiple copies of GD and the CLI php is loading a different one than Apache PHP.

Comment: I didn't think to look at that... But there is read access all the way through the tree and the file gd.so for everyone. Running a find right now on gd.so but its taking forever. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you shure the gd.so is in this directory?

Did you check the usual things, like file access right for the webserver to the .so file?

Sounds like a permissions problem to me

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a site that had gd.so precompiled in 64 bit. Just plopped the file in the directory and life was good.

In case anyone is wondering:

http://www.viames.it/mac-os-x.html